# Selenium WebDriver unable to find element that is clearly there

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

Ok, this statement is giving me an error:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("870"))).selectByVisibleText(reason);


org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"870"}
```

Command duration or timeout: 1.02 seconds

And I have tried finding it by xpath, and id, and I know for a fact its there with the id 870. I have tried putting in sleeps to make sure it is loaded too.

Thanks in advance.

I am using version 2.5 with Firefox.

Element is

```
<select id="870" class="ui-widget-content reactor alias_reason" data-bind="options: questionValueGroup.questionValues, optionsText: 'qu…: properties(), setSingleSelected: $parent.providerAnswers()" paid="37" group="6" style="background-color: #FCFDFD;"></select>
```

edit 2: I figured it out guys, I just used chromes xpath selector tool and it gave me a different xpath that works.

Comment: Share the html of the element in question.

Comment: When `NoSuchElementException` is thrown, it's generally due to two reasons.  1. The element is inside a frame or iframe, in which case you'll need to use `switchTo.frame("frame_identifier")` or 2. The element loads slowly, and you'll need to wait for the element to load.

Comment: What browser? What version of that browser? What version of Selenium?

Comment: Check edits. Also, I added a sleep(10000) before looking for it and it still happens.

Comment: Selenium v2.5, with what version of Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that the fact you have an id which starts with a number is confusing Selenium.  W3C standards say that Ids cannot start with numbers, therefore try the following;

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.css("[id='870']"))).selectByVisibleText(reason);
```

or

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='870']"))).selectByVisibleText(reason);
```